# Getting "ScriptHalted" when trying to run add-migration

Tags: database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working through a .Net Core MVC Tutorial, and am currently attempting to add a migration with EF Tools. Upon trying `add-migration migrationName` in the package manager console I get "ScriptHalted" as a return. I get this result for any of the EF tools commands, and have verified it is installed properly.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you write in your web project  dotnet ef migrations add Test ... what you get?

Comment: In the package manager console?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing "dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate" in the CLI worked instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-2.0#introduction-to-migrations

Answer (score 1):

If it's in Windows 7 x86. update the power shell version to 'Version 5.3.0.6251'.

Visual Studio (Version 2019 16.3.4)